# How to find the best coefficient vector using cross-validation

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, cross-validation, ridge-regression

So basically my dataset is divided into 5 train and 5 test folds.

This is how I did in scikit:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
k_fold=cross_validation.KFold(n=len(tourism_train_X),n_folds=5) 
I set the regularisation parameter like this:
```

## Generating alpha values for regularization parameters

```
n_alphas = 200
alphas = np.logspace(-10, -1, n_alphas)
```

Now , my doubt is, for each train and test fold I do something like this.

```
for a in alphas:
    ridge_tourism.set_params(alpha=a)
    index=0
    for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
        ridge_tourism.fit(tourism_train_X[train_indices], tourism_train_Y[train_indices])  # Fitting the model
        coefs.append(ridge_tourism.coef_)
```

The problem is it would give me coefficient vector for each of the five training fold within each alpha. All I want is for each alpha what is the best coefficient vector chosen. How do we get that? How do we choose out of 5 train sets which coefficient vector is finally reported for that alpha?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Often you use cross validation to choose a best regularization parameter (your $\alpha$). The optimal parameter is that which results in the least mean hold out error across all the folds (sometimes a more strict parameter is chosen based on the standard deviation of the error across folds, `glmnet` has the option, for example).  With this parameter safely in hand, the model is refit on the full training data with the given regularization parameter to determine the final model coefficients.

If possible, you should hold out some data out from training to assess the performance of the final model.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what CV is for. I think you want to be using grid search to optimize the parameter:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: Grid search is being used here - `for a in alphas` is a one dimensional grid search.  Then for each $\alpha$ a cross validation should be used to estimate the out of sample error.  I think the point the user is missing is that they don't need a "final" set of coefficients for each $\alpha$ in the search, only the appropriate $\alpha$ chosen through cross validation.

It's definately a fair point that the built in `grid_search` should be used.

Comment: @MatthewDrury: Right! I didn't read the code carefully and missed that.